# SQL AGENT SSIS JOBS IN HUNG STATE

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I'm using:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU10-GDR) (KB4052725) - 12.0.5571.0 (X64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
OS version - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
```

Last few months we are facing the issues 2 -3 times

We have observed that Jobs which are scheduled using T-SQL are getting completed successfully, issue is with SQL jobs which are configured by SSIS and those are getting halted after some time post re-starting the integration service.

The SSIS Jobs will works for while and start to get hung and wont do anything -Can anyone tell me what the issue could be why only this one SSIS job is hung, and all others work fine?

Comment: You need to do some analysis of logs. Where are the packages hung? Do the packages start? I had a similar issue years ago and it had to do with a custom log provider. Once we removed the provider it stopped happening

Comment: Yes the Package Starts - No errors, it just keep on executing
if it throws any error we can find the root cause
Nothing is logged in event log, sql logs, agent logs
No Blocks or locks
-Works fine when running via SSDT
This is only one I can spot is Microsoft SSIS service Registry seting Specifying configuration file doesn't exist- Attempting To load Defaullt config file

Comment: It sounds like you don’t have package logging turned on at all. Check the package log.

Comment: Just realized when I kick off the job it doesn't do anything not even starts

Comment: Do you think its the same issues with the Package logging issue on the ssis?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't even logging so no.